# How to replace "|" in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a dataframe which contains

"HYD_SOA_UNBLOCK~SOA_BLOCK-UK|SOA_BLOCK-DE||SOA_BLOCK-FR||SOA_BLOCK-IT||SOA_BLOCK-ES|"

I want the result to be -

"HYD_SOA_UNBLOCK~SOA_BLOCK-UK|SOA_BLOCK-DE|SOA_BLOCK-FR|SOA_BLOCK-IT|SOA_BLOCK-ES|"

I tried:

```
leadtemp$collate = gsub("||","|",leadtemp$collate)
```

but it is not working.

Please help me replace "||" with "|"

Comment: Just add `fixed = TRUE` to your `gsub()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MrFlick suggested, include fixed = TRUE in your gsub statement. The problem occurs because "|" is a Regular Expression operator. Using fixed = TRUE tells gsub to assume the pattern is a string and not a RegEx.

```
leadtemp$collate = gsub("||","|",leadtemp$collate, fixed=TRUE)
```

Another (although more complicated) way of doing it would be to escape all the |s:

```
leadtemp$collate = gsub("\\|\\|","\\|",leadtemp$collate)
```

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a metacharacter. As you can read [here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/74603_76cd14d5983f47408fdf0b323550b846.html), metacharacters need to be escaped out of with a `\`. `\` is also a metacharacter so it must be escaped out of in the same way. So whenever you want to refer to a `|` in a string, you have to put `\\|`. This should make your code work:

```
leadtemp$collate = gsub("\\|\\|","\\|",leadtemp$collate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
gsub("[|]{2}", "|", leadtemp$collate)
```

I have defined character class comprising the pipe character and forced gsub to look for exactly two occurrences.Result is:

```
"HYD_SOA_UNBLOCK~SOA_BLOCK-UK|SOA_BLOCK-DE|SOA_BLOCK-FR|SOA_BLOCK-IT|SOA_BLOCK-ES|"
```